# understanding repl in puppet code

Tags: puppet

I am looking at puppet code that looks something like

```
class {
      users => {
           'repl@%' => {
                ensure => present,
                .
            }
       }
 }
```

What does "repl" do? I cant find much information online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of anonymization almost hides the important points. But I belive that this is supposed to be the declaration of a hash, meant for use with the `create_resources` function.

It works like this: If you have a large number of resources that should not take all the space in your class (this reason is contrived), you can convert it to a hash structure instead.

```
mysql_grant {
    'repl@%':
        ensure => present,
        rights => 'REPLICATION CLIENT';
}
```

This becomes a hash, stored in a variable.

```
$users = {
    'repl@%' => {
        ensure => present,
        rights => 'REPLICATION CLIENT',
    }
}
```

This can then be used to declare this (and more resources in the hash, if there is more than one) in a simple line.

```
create_resources('mysql_grant', $users)
```

I'm guessing that you are looking at `grants` because `repl@%` is a typical MySQL notation that means `user with name "repl" from any client`.

TL;DR it is a domain specific identifier and has no special meaning to Puppet itself.